# How to set NULL if REGEX doesn't has any matches?

Tags: php, regex

I have a regex which returns just numbers from string:

```
$str  = "this is 1 str, 2";
$numb = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$str);
echo $numb; // output: 12
```

But if string doesn't be containing number, then it will return nothing. Now I want it returns `NULL` if string isn't containing number. Something like this:

```
$str  = "this is one str";
$numb = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$str);
echo $numb; // current output:
            // what I want: null
```

**Note:** That `null` isn't a string, it should be something like this: `$numb = null;`

How can I do that?

Comment: assign null to it if it's empty?

Comment: `$numb = strlen($numb) === 0 ? null : $numb;`?

Comment: @Idos Yes exactlu ...! *(btw I don't want do that using if-statemtn)*

Comment: `if (empty($numb)) $numb = null;`

Comment: @stribizhev Well, Cannot I do that using just that regex?

Comment: A preg_replace returns a string, either with characters, or empty, or NULL if an error occurred. You cannot do it other way than assigning the null value after checking if you have an empty string as a result.

Comment: @stribizhev Oh I see. Good point.

Comment: Why not use http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php to see if it is a number?

Comment: @chris85 Two reasons: 1. That function isn't sensitive to `.` *(I want pure integer)*. 2. I don't want just check it, actually I need to extract all the numbers from string.

Comment: Oh, I see, there also is http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php but seems like you'll need a regex anyway to get numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that *just* by using regex (since `preg_replace` returns a string or NULL if it encountered an error) . You actually need to check the variable and assign `null` if needed:

```
$numb = $numb ?: null;
```

Comment: Even shorter `$numb = $numb ?: null;` ;)

Answer (score 1):

You may return null on having empty values:

```
$str  = "this is one str";
$numb = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$str);
echo ( ! empty( $numb ) ? $numb : null );
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the pure regex solution you're looking for but here is one **work-around** of doing this using `filter_var`:

Define a function:

```
function isint($val) {
   $i=filter_var($val, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
   return empty($i) ? NULL : $i;
}
```

Then use it as:

```
var_dump( filter_var('Doe, Jane123 Sue', FILTER_CALLBACK, array('options' => 'isint')) );
//=> string(3) "123"

var_dump( filter_var('Doe, Jane Sue', FILTER_CALLBACK, array('options' => 'isint')) );
//=> NULL
```